# Postfix: redirect all incoming emails to a script

Tags: email, postfix-mta

I need to setup a postfix server to receive emails and post the email bodies to a bbs.

Postfix version: 2.10.2

/etc/postfix/main.cf:

```
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
command_directory = /usr/bin
daemon_directory = /usr/lib/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
mail_owner = postfix
myhostname = mail.mydummydomain.com
mydomain = mydummydomain.com
myorigin = $mydomain
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
local_recipient_maps =
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/redirect
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, 192.168.56.0/24, 192.168.79.0/24
alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
alias_database = $alias_maps
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command =
         PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
         ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
sendmail_path = /usr/bin/sendmail
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq
setgid_group = postdrop
html_directory = no
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
sample_directory = /etc/postfix/sample
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix
```

(I have to add "local_recipient_maps =" otherwise the email will be rejected with "550 5.1.1 <...>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in local recipient table".)

/etc/postfix/redirect:

```
/*/ tomyscript
```

/etc/postfix/aliases:

```
MAILER-DAEMON:  postmaster
postmaster:     root
bin:            root
daemon:         root
named:          root
nobody:         root
uucp:           root
www:            root
ftp-bugs:       root
postfix:        root
manager:        root
dumper:         root
operator:       root
abuse:          postmaster
tomyscript:     "|/tmp/myscript.py >> /tmp/mail.log"
decode:         root
```

When I send a test email to my postfix server, apparently it is not redirected to my script:

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mail.mydummydomain.com ESMTP Postfix
ehlo mydummydomain.com
250-mail.mydummydomain.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
mail from:<aaa@mydummydomain.com>
250 2.1.0 Ok
rcpt to:<bbb@mydummydomain.com>
250 2.1.5 Ok
data
354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
this is the email body
.
250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 825061A003D
```

Postfix log:

```
Dec 27 15:04:28 Arch postfix/smtpd[2812]: connect from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Dec 27 15:06:26 Arch postfix/smtpd[2812]: 825061A003D: client=localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Dec 27 15:06:35 Arch postfix/cleanup[2814]: 825061A003D: message-id=<20131227070626.825061A003D@mail.mydummydomain.com>
Dec 27 15:06:35 Arch postfix/qmgr[2804]: 825061A003D: from=<aaa@mydummydomain.com>, size=368, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec 27 15:06:35 Arch postfix/local[2815]: 825061A003D: to=<bbb@mydummydomain.com>, relay=local, delay=110, delays=110/0.01/0/0.03, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (unknown user: "bbb")
Dec 27 15:06:35 Arch postfix/cleanup[2814]: 7BA861A0041: message-id=<20131227070635.7BA861A0041@mail.mydummydomain.com>
Dec 27 15:06:35 Arch postfix/bounce[2816]: 825061A003D: sender non-delivery notification: 7BA861A0041
Dec 27 15:06:35 Arch postfix/qmgr[2804]: 7BA861A0041: from=<>, size=2209, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec 27 15:06:35 Arch postfix/qmgr[2804]: 825061A003D: removed
Dec 27 15:06:35 Arch postfix/local[2815]: 7BA861A0041: to=<aaa@mydummydomain.com>, relay=local, delay=0.02, delays=0.01/0/0/0.01, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (unknown user: "aaa")
Dec 27 15:06:35 Arch postfix/qmgr[2804]: 7BA861A0041: removed
Dec 27 15:06:57 Arch postfix/smtpd[2812]: disconnect from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
```

myscript.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

import sys

for line in sys.stdin.read().split('\n'):
    print line
```

Any idea?

Comment: you should be sending email to `tomyscript@mydummydomain.com`.

Comment: @alvits Thanks! It works! But how to redirect all incoming emails with recipient *@mydummydomain.com to my script?

Comment: I finally understand what you were asking for. You can define a catchall local user who will receive all emails for unknown users. Just add `luser_relay = tomyscript` in your postfix configuration

Comment: @alvits Thanks! It works!  Now I can send email to an arbitrary recipient at my domain by "telnet localhost smtp", and the email gets redirected. But when I send an email by a real email service provider (e.g. gmail. (yes, the email can reach my server)), the email will be rejected: "Recipient's address does not exist. (account is not activated, or has been stopped). (smtp session response [550 5.1.1 <4f3a2327c2fc344ea3007bcb@....com>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in local recipient table] while sending command [RCPT TO: <4f3a2327c2fc344ea3007bcb@....com> ])".  Any idea?

Comment: @alvits Postfix configurations: http://ur1.ca/gchf5

Comment: Can you post the smtp log?

Comment: @alvits Sorry, it's not postfix issue, it's actually dns issue.  The emails arrived at my another postfix server.

Comment: I'm glad you resolved it. :)